# Random Dynamical System reference book

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for a reference on random dynamical systems. Most of my past research has been in stochastic differential equations, but I've been reading on RDS lately. Currently, stochastic bifurcation and the stability of RDS appeal to me.

I've been trying to work through Arnold's "Random Dynamical Systems", but it's a tough read and doesn't feel intuitive to me. Is there an alternative reference? or should I suck it up and continue reading.

Thanks in advance.

MJ

Comment: take a look at https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A37 ; especially, try combining 37H and 37-0x

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks